# What am I missing from my code to meet all the requirements of my program?

Tags: java

I have to design and implement a program that counts the number of integer values from user input. Produce a table listing the values you identify as integers from the input. Provide the sum and average of the numbers.This is what I have so far.

```
public class Table {
public static void main(String [] strAng) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;

    for(int number = min;
    number <= max; ++number) {
        sum += number;
    }



    System.out.print("Sum:" +sum);
    System.out.print("Average:" +average);
```

Comment: You are not getting any user input?...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Well, obviously, what's missing is any attempt to read user input. So do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and attempt to do that. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, there is little chance of it meeting the reqs. This won't, because you haven't initialized `average` (plus missing closing braces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not get an input from user and also you do nothing to make average.

Try this code, and if you have other requirements, update the question.

```
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the integers with space between each two integer: ");
    String inputNumberFilePath = userInputScanner.nextLine();

    String[] numStrArray = inputNumberFilePath.split(" ");

    for (String string : numStrArray) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(string);
    }

    average = (double) sum / (double) numStrArray.length;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
```

output sample:

```
Please enter the integers with space between each two integer: 
10 20 30 40 50
Sum: 150
Average: 30.0
```

Comment: you have to cast `numStrArray.length` to `double`, else java is rounding the result: `average = sum / (double) numStrArray.length;`

Comment: yes, you are right, both `sum` and `length` must be cast to `double`, I have change it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but it could be. With this code you enter a string with integers "in it". The integers get extracted, counted and have sum & average operations performed on what is basically a bar graph. Hope this helps.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Table {
```

This part is used to read ANY user input Strings included.

```
public static String getInput(){
    String outPut = "";
    System.out.println("Type something to parse: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        outPut = sc.nextLine();
    }
    return outPut;
}
```

Here we build our "bar graph":

```
public static Map<Long,Integer> makeTable(String input){

    Map<Long,Integer> table = new HashMap<>();

    long in = Long.parseLong(input);
    long lastDig = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while(in > 0){

    lastDig = in % 10;
    in /= 10;

    if(!table.containsKey(lastDig)) {
        table.put(lastDig, count);
    } else {
        table.replace(lastDig,count,count+1);
    }

    }

    return table;
}
```

Here we calculate the sum:

```
public static int sum(Map<Long,Integer> table){
    int sum = 0;
    for (Long key: table.keySet()
         ) {
        sum += (key*table.get(key));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here we get our average:

```
public static int average(Map<Long,Integer> table){
    int sum = 0;
    int divisor = 0;
    for (Long key: table.keySet()
            ) {
        sum += (key*table.get(key));
        divisor += table.get(key);
    }
    return sum/divisor;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    String input = "";
    input = getInput();
    System.out.println("Unsanitized In: " + input);
```

Here the integer digits are extracted!

```
    input = input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]","");
    Long.parseLong(input);

    System.out.println("Sanitized In: " + input);

    Map<Long,Integer> myMap = makeTable(input);
    System.out.println(myMap);

    System.out.println("Sum:" +sum(myMap));
    System.out.print("Average:" + average(myMap));

}
```

}

**Our example output for: asdf45313ha is:**

```
 Unsanitized In: asdf45313ha
 Sanitized In: 45313
 {1=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=1}
 Sum:16
 Average:3
```